# Open intervals in $R^1$ is open

Tags: real-analysis

I know this question would seem like a duplicate, but I here I provided a proof of the statement I just don't know how to justify certain thing in my proof.

Proof:

Suppose y is an arbitrarily element inside (a,b). Now consider B(y,r) where $r := min(y - a,b - y)$ we have $B(y,r) = (y - r,y + r)$.

suppose that $min(y - a,b - y) = y-a$.

Consider $B(y,r) = (y - (y - a),y + (y - a)) = (a,2y - a)$ I am not sure how can I prove that $2y - a < b$ in that case ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption $min(y -a , b -y) = y - a$ implies $y - a \leq b - y$ and this is equivalent to $2 y - a \leq b$.

Comment: Yes yes I just noticed that !! so stupid...

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{a+b}2$ is the midpoint of the interval $(a,b)$, your assumption that $y-a<b-y$ is equivalent to $y<\frac{a+b}2$, or $2y-a<b$.

Answer (score 1):

You supposed 
$\text{min}(y-a, b-y)=y-a$, i.e. $y-a\leq b-y$.